# How to save a module from one computer and import into into another computer in IntelliJ with Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven module in IntelliJ which works fine from one computer. I have saved the ".iml" file together with the project in Git. When I check it out on another computer,

1. "New Project"
2. then "File" -> "New Module from Existing Sources" -> Select the ".iml" file, the structure is all there, but no Maven dependencies are resolved.

How do I get IntelliJ to download and import the Maven dependencies?

Things I have tried:

- "Re-build Project"
- Right-click the module and "Re-build module"
- "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" (both invalidate and restart)
- "Re-import All Maven Projects", this simply deleted the two Maven modules from the project. I then had to re-create the modules as above, once they were there again I had the same problem.

On the comand-line "mvn" is able to import the project and resolve all dependencies just fine.

Additional information:

- The ".iml" file, when I look at it in a text editor, does not have any absolute paths in it.

Here is a picture of the module settings window:

[image]

Comment: Where's your pom.xml?

Comment: The pom.xml is in the root directory of each module, along-side the ".iml" file, in the same position as it is on the other computer where I created the module.

Comment: The .iml file is Idea-specific; if you're building a Maven project you do *not* need an .iml file, but you *do* need to import the POM.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839

Comment: @CrazyCode that implies I should add my ".iml" files in Git which is what I'm doing - or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Check the comments, you should not share .iml and library files for the Maven and Gradle projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just import the project on another PC, don't rely on the iml files. Some even consider it bad practice to commit IDE specific files in maven projects, as not everyone on a project might use the same version or even a different IDE. If you take a look at popular .gitignore files (e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/lordofthelake/5833336)), you'll most often find that any IDE specific files get excluded.

Consider importing the projects pom.xml:
Import Project -> from external model -> Maven

EDIT
JetBrains recommends to NOT include the iml file with Maven or Gradle projects, see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839)